# C# .net core 3.1 WPF close without any exception

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

My application WPF .net core 3.1 run in win10 home and around two or three days, it was closed and didn't catch any exception. I had put exception handler in app

```
    void App_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e) 
    {
        Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException += Current_DispatcherUnhandledException;
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
    }
    private void Current_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        string error = "An unhandled exception just occured: " + e.Exception.Message +
                Environment.NewLine + "WHERE: " + e.Exception.StackTrace;
        string title = "DispatcherUnhandledException";
        Log.Logger.Fatal(e.Exception, "Current_DispatcherUnhandledException");
        MessageBox.Show(error, title, MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    private void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        var ex = e.ExceptionObject as Exception;
        string error = "An unhandled exception just occured and application will be exit: " + ex.Message +
                Environment.NewLine + "WHERE: " + ex.StackTrace;
        string title = "UnhandledException";
        Log.Logger.Fatal(ex, "CurrentDomain_UnhandledException");
        MessageBox.Show(error, title, MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like a "memory leak."  Fix that, and you won't need the handlers.

Comment: If you use `Log.Logger` - log doesn't contains error details? Or at exception moment its is disposed so it call causes another exception which couldn't be handled at same time :?

Comment: Or a stack overflow error, or an error in your handler, or thr log not flushing correctly, check event viewer